# How to pass ColorPicker property to root widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to learn how to pass the ColorPicker object property to the main class MainWindow from the kv file.
I have created classes ColPopup and PickColor and I am able to get the information about the selected color, but I am unable to get the color value passed to MainWindow from PickColor.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? I would like to have the Object Property colorpicker set to the colorpicker so that I can access the .color method later.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
#kivy.require("1.11.1")

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.colorpicker import ColorPicker
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1200')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '600')
     

class ColPopup(Popup):
    pass

class PickColor(ColorPicker):
    pass

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    colorpicker = ObjectProperty()
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.range_tab_action_grid_buttons = {}
        self.create_actions()
        
    def choose_color(self, instance):
        ColPopup().open()
        print("color picked for ", instance, "with current color", instance.background_color)
        print(self.colorpicker)
                    
    def create_actions(self):   
        
        for i in range(1, 4):
            grid = BoxLayout(size=(180, 20), size_hint=(None, None))
            checkbox = CheckBox(group="Actions",allow_no_selection=False, size_hint=(.2,1))
            grid.add_widget(checkbox)
            label = Label(text="Action"+str(i)+" color", size_hint=(.6,1)) 
            grid.add_widget(label)
                        
            colored_button = Button(background_color=[0, 45, 100, 1], size_hint=(.2,0.8), pos_hint={'center_y':0.5})
            colored_button.bind(on_press = self.choose_color)
            
            grid.add_widget(colored_button)
            self.ids.range_tab_action_grid.add_widget(grid)
            self.range_tab_action_grid_buttons["Action"+str(i)] = {"grid":grid, "checkbox":checkbox, "label":label, "colored_button":colored_button} #, "colorpicker":colorpicker}
            
            # Check the first box
            self.range_tab_action_grid_buttons["Action1"]["checkbox"].active = True

        #print(self.range_tab_action_grid_buttons["Action1"][3].background_color)       
        
        
class ColorPickerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ColorPickerApp().run()
```

colorpicker.kv

```
# File name: main.py
#:kivy 1.11.1  

<ColPopup>:
    title: 'Pick a Color'
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.6
    colorpicker: colorpicker
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        PickColor:
            id: colorpicker
        Button:
            text: "Select color"
            on_release: root.dismiss()
            size_hint: 0.3,0.3
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.75,"top":0.0}
             

<Button>:
    font_size: 10
    color: 1,1,1,1
    size_hint: 0.05, 0.05
    
                   
<MainWindow>:                        
    BoxLayout:
        id: range_tab_action_grid
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"right":0.0, "top":1.0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the `on_release` of your `Select color` to call a method in your `MainWindow`. If you modify your `kv` rule for `ColPopup`:

```
<ColPopup>:
    title: 'Pick a Color'
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.6
    colorpicker: colorpicker
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        PickColor:
            id: colorpicker
        Button:
            text: "Select color"
            on_release:
                app.root.chosen_color(colorpicker.color)
                root.dismiss()
            size_hint: 0.3,0.3
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.75,"top":0.0}
```

This adds a call to `chosen_color()` to the `Button`.

Then modifying the `MainWindow` class:

```
class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    colorpicker = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.range_tab_action_grid_buttons = {}
        self.create_actions()

    def choose_color(self, instance):
        for k,v in self.range_tab_action_grid_buttons.items():
            if v['colored_button'] == instance and v['checkbox'].active:
                colpopup = ColPopup()
                self.colorpicker = colpopup.colorpicker
                colpopup.open()
                return

    def chosen_color(self, color):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.get_color, 5)
        for k,v in self.range_tab_action_grid_buttons.items():
            if v['checkbox'].active:
                v['colored_button'].background_color = color
                return

    def get_color(self, dt):
        print('color:', self.colorpicker.color)

    def create_actions(self):
        .
        .
        .
```

The `choose_color()` method sets the `colorpicker` `ObjectProperty`. It also only opens the `ColorPicker` if the `Button` is in the active row.

The `chosen_color()` method only changes the color of the active `Button`.

Also note that the `background_color` of the `Button` acts as a multiplier of the default texture. You can change that by setting `background_normal=''`.

Comment: Thank you John. Nice explanation, it is much more clear now. Thanks for pointing out the `background_normal` also, I wondered why my buttons were greyish. Do I understand it correctly that the `Clock.schedule_once` is only for printing the chosen color?

Comment: Yes, I just added that to verify that you can still get the color after the `Popup` is dismissed. And that only works because a reference to the `ColorPicker` is saved, otherwise it would get garbage collected.